Keycloak can't change AD passwords
I have a Keycloak instance that is talking to an AD on Server 2016 via LDAPS. I have verified that the connection to the server is working, that the connection is encrypted, and that the Bind user in keycloak can authenticate.
AND YET, when attempting to change a password, I get the following error:

The keycloak bind user has FULL write access over the whole domain, so I really do not see any reason for AD to reject external write access.
Connecting to the server via ldapsearch with ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://<DC FQDN>:636 -D "cn=Keycloak-Sync2,ou=SpecialUsers,ou=<company>,dc=<company domain>,dc=de" -b "ou=Team,ou=<Company>,dc=<company domain>,dc=de" -w "<password>"
The BindDN (-D option) is exactly equal to the Bind DN in keycloak, and the Base DN (-b option) is exactly equal to the users DN in keycloak, and I get a list of all the users as a result.
I also get the following error in the Keycloak log:
8:26:53,153 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPIdentityStoreRegistry] (Timer-2) Creating new LDAP Store for the LDAP storage provider: 'ldap', LDAP Configuration: {fullSyncPeriod=[86400], pagination=[true], connectionPooling=[false], usersDn=[ou=Team,ou=<company name>,dc=<company domain>,dc=de], cachePolicy=[DEFAULT], useKerberosForPasswordAuthentication=[false], importEnabled=[true], enabled=[true], bindDn=[CN=Keycloak-Sync2,ou=SpecialUsers,ou=<company name>,dc=<company domain>,dc=de], usernameLDAPAttribute=[sAMAccountName], changedSyncPeriod=[900], lastSync=[1734287212], vendor=[ad], uuidLDAPAttribute=[objectGUID], connectionUrl=[ldaps://dc02.<company domain>.de:636], allowKerberosAuthentication=[false], syncRegistrations=[false], authType=[simple], debug=[false], searchScope=[2], useTruststoreSpi=[ldapsOnly], usePasswordModifyExtendedOp=[true], trustEmail=[true], priority=[0], userObjectClasses=[person, organizationalPerson, user], rdnLDAPAttribute=[sAMAccountName], editMode=[WRITABLE], validatePasswordPolicy=[false], batchSizeForSync=[1000]}, binaryAttributes: []
18:26:53,200 INFO  [org.keycloak.truststore.SSLSocketFactory] (Timer-2) No truststore provider found - using default SSLSocketFactory
18:26:54,022 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (Timer-2) Sync of federation mapper 'role-mapper' finished. Status: UserFederationSyncResult [ 0 imported roles, 67 roles already exists in Keycloak ]
18:26:54,027 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (Timer-2) Sync changed users from LDAP to local store: realm: <COMPANY DOMAIN>.DE, federation provider: ldap, last sync time: Sun Dec 15 18:07:41 GMT 2024
18:26:54,218 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (Timer-2) Sync changed users finished: 0 imported users, 0 updated users
18:36:58,665 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=10.42.0.2, error=expired_code, restart_after_timeout=true, authSessionParentId=89cdcdbd-5f32-47a2-9c69-1d83f8eca814, authSessionTabId=g8xANkYl1M0
18:37:04,130 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=10.42.0.2, error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, redirect_uri=https://auth.<company domain>.de/auth/admin/master/console/, code_id=89cdcdbd-5f32-47a2-9c69-1d83f8eca814, username=<windows username>, authSessionParentId=89cdcdbd-5f32-47a2-9c69-1d83f8eca814, authSessionTabId=g8xANkYl1M0
18:38:30,022 WARN  [org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UserResource] (default task-3) Could not update user password.: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: Could not modify attribute for DN [CN=<name of user>,OU=Team,OU=<company name>,DC=<company domain>,DC=de]
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.modifyAttributes(LDAPOperationManager.java:609)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPIdentityStore.updateADPassword(LDAPIdentityStore.java:399)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPIdentityStore.updatePassword(LDAPIdentityStore.java:367)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.updateCredential(LDAPStorageProvider.java:666)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.1//org.keycloak.credential.UserCredentialStoreManager.updateCredential(UserCredentialStoreManager.java:184)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UserResource.resetPassword(UserResource.java:614)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@17.0.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.1//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@17.0.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - 00000005: SecErr: DSID-031A11EF, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0
]; remaining name 'CN=<name of user>,OU=Team,OU=<company name>,DC=<company domain>,DC=de'
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3267)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3205)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2996)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1504)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:277)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:192)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.modifyAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:172)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.modifyAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:172)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager$6.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:590)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager$6.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:586)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:731)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:711)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.modifyAttributesNaming(LDAPOperationManager.java:586)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation@17.0.1//org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.modifyAttributes(LDAPOperationManager.java:607)
    ... 87 more

What could the reason be that AD does not let Keycloak change the user password?

If I use the domain administrator account, it works, but even if I give that user FULL access over all objects in the whole domain, it does not work.

(INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS) what account are you attempting to change the password for? Is it a protected account or a regular user account?

The keycloak bind user has FULL write access over the whole domain Note that protected AD accounts do not inherit that permission, protected accounts have permissions applied directly to them.

@GregAskew I was simply attempting to change the password of a normal Domain User - I applied all permissions at every level, just in case it made a difference.

But can you tell me more about AD accounts not inheriting permissions, that sounds like it could be the issue

Accounts that are members of privileged groups are protected by the SDProp process.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory

Also it sounds like the activity is attempting an administrative reset of the password, which is subject to fewer restrictions. A password change typically occurs during a user-invoked activity where the current password is provided, and is subject to more rules/policies.
